React Hook Form - generic Controller wrapper for array of items
I'm trying to build couple of generic input components using mui and react-hook-form to handle an array of generic ojects.
I have a Controller wrapped around the Mui input.
import { CellProps } from '../../../types';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

type EditTextCellProps<T extends object> = CellProps<T, number>;

export interface FormValues {
    id: string;
    type: string;
}

export const EditTextCell = ({ row: { index }, column: { id } }: EditTextCellProps<FormValues>) => {
    const { control } = useFormContext<{ items: FormValues[] }>();

    return (
        <Controller
            render={({
                field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
                fieldState: { invalid, isTouched, isDirty, error }
            }) => (
                <TextField
                    size="small"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onChange} // send value to hook form
                    onBlur={onBlur} // notify when input is touched
                    inputRef={ref} // wire up the input ref
                    error={Boolean(error)}
                    helperText={error?.message}
                />
            )}
            name={`items.${index}.${id}`}
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
        />
    );
};


And now I want it to be generic
import { CellProps } from '../../../types';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { Controller, FieldValues, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

type EditTextCellProps<T extends object> = CellProps<T, number>;

export const EditTextCell = <T extends FieldValues,>({ row: { index }, column: { id } }: EditTextCellProps<T>) => {
    const { control } = useFormContext<{ items: T[] }>();

    return (
        <Controller
            render={({
                field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
                fieldState: { invalid, isTouched, isDirty, error }
            }) => (
                <TextField
                    size="small"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onChange} // send value to hook form
                    onBlur={onBlur} // notify when input is touched
                    inputRef={ref} // wire up the input ref
                    error={Boolean(error)}
                    helperText={error?.message}
                />
            )}
            name={`items.${index}.${id}`}
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
        />
    );
};

But I'm getting an error related to the name:

Type 'items.${number}.${Extract<keyof T, string>}' is not assignable to type '"items" | items.${PathImpl<number, T, T[] | { items: T[]; }>}'.
Type 'items.${number}.${string}' is not assignable to type '"items" | items.${PathImpl<number, T, T[] | { items: T[]; }>}'.ts(2322)
controller.d.ts(20, 5): The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { render: ({ field, fieldState, formState, }: { field: ControllerRenderProps<{ items: T[]; }, "items" | items.${PathImpl<number, T, T[] | { items: T[]; }>}>; fieldState: ControllerFieldState; formState: UseFormStateReturn<...>; }) => ReactElement<...>; } & UseControllerProps<...>'


